# How do i count the number of occurrence for a string in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to count the number of occurrence for this phrase "SMM:" in each row in column AJ starting from row 2 and then assign the assign the value for each row to column BL starting from row 2.

```
Sub calculateamlp()


Dim charactercount As Integer
Dim rangeAG As Range
Dim cellCheck As Range
Dim f As Integer
f = 2
 Worksheets("pptsr").Activate

Set rangeAG2 = Range("BL2", Range("BL2").End(xlDown))
Set rangeAG = Range("Aj2", Range("Aj2").End(xlDown))
For Each cellCheck In rangeAG

        charactercount = Len(cellCheck) - Len(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cellCheck, ":", ""))


        Worksheets("pptsr").Range("BL2" & f).Value = charactercount

   f = f + 1
Next cellCheck

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post screen shots of the data? It will help me make an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exact match you should use "vbBinaryCompare". If you want to match "smm:" with "SMM:" then you should use "vbTextCompare". Try this:

```
Sub calculateamlp()
Dim count As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("pptsr")
With ws
    rw = .Range("AJ" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To rw
        For j = 1 To Len(.Cells(i, "AJ"))
            If InStr(j, .Cells(i, "AJ"), "SMM:", vbTextCompare) Then
                count = count + 1
                j = InStr(j, .Cells(i, "AJ"), "SMM:", vbTextCompare)
            End If
        Next j
        .Cells(i, "BL") = count
        count = 0
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Tehscript, I edited your post from "SMM" to "SMM:", I think you missed the colon in the post up top.

Comment: @Tehscript, I tried the code but the answer is not counted in Column BL

Comment: @Tehscript, I just noticed that it changes the heading in BL1

Comment: @Richmond I tried now and Cell BL1 stays intact. It is not possible because counting starts from 2: `For i = 2 To rw`. Maybe something else has changed it earlier?

Comment: @Tehscript, you are right BL1 stays intact when tried with a sample data. I am away from the workbook and so I will try it again when I get to it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This function get the count by counting the number of elements in Splitting the String using the with the Substring.

```
Function getStrOccurenceCount(Text As String, SubString As String)
    getStrOccurenceCount = UBound(Split(Text, SubString))
End Function
```

You could modify your code like this

> Worksheets("pptsr").Range("BL2" & f).Value = getStrOccurenceCount(cellCheck.Text, "SMM:")

Here is how you could use the `getStrOccurenceCount` with arrays to improve your efficiency.

```
Sub calculateamlp2()
    Const SUBSTRING As String = "SMM:"
    Dim rangeAG As Range
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Set rangeAG = Range("AJ2", Range("AJ2").End(xlDown))

    data = rangeAG.Value

    For x = 1 To UBound(data)
        data(x, 1) = getStrOccurenceCount(CStr(data(x, 1)), SUBSTRING)
    Next

    rangeAG.EntireRow.Columns("BL").Value = data
End Sub
```

Demo: Sample data 999,999 rows, execution time 0.9375 Seconds:

[image]

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, I also tried your code in between Sub calculateamlp2() and End Sub. But I get an error saying "Sub or Function not defined" Then it highlights Sub calculateamlp2()

Comment: It sounds like the you don't have the getStrOccurenceCount  function in the code module with calculateamlp2 or in a public code module